# Two FixtureSetup in the same Fixture

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Do you know any methods/workarrounds to have *different* FixtureSetup for two Test cases in the same class?

(I cant create two independent Test classes for that.)

Comment: 'I cant create two independent Test classes for that.'... Why? If they are different, they are different...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. The primary intention of a TestFixture is that it groups a bunch of tests that require the same setup.